# Inconsistencies in environments

Tags: spacing, formatting, environments

I have noticed that I get different results when I use an environment and when I type my code "directly", which I presume is not supposed to happen. For example, here is the code for a definition (the gaps are to be filled by students):

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=17cm]
\textbf{\underline{Définition}} Une ........................ associe à 
chaque nombre réel $x$ d'un ................................ un nombre réel 
que l'on note ...........  et qu'on appelle  
................................ de $x$.
\end{tcolorbox}
```

[image]

I write definitions fairly frequently so I defined an environment:

```
\newenvironment{definition}
{\begin{tcolorbox}[width=17cm]
\textbf{\underline{Définition}} }
{\end{tcolorbox}}
```

which is just the above code without the actual text of the definition.

Now when I invoke the environment and add the text:

```
\begin{definition}
Une ........................ associe à chaque nombre réel $x$ d'un         
................................ un nombre réel que l'on note ...........          
et qu'on appelle  ................................ de $x$.
\end{definition}
```

I get this:

[image]

The spacing between lines is not the same, among other details.

EDIT: Here's a compilable code showing the problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.4}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{definitionn}
{\begin{tcolorbox}[width=17cm]
\textbf{\underline{Définition}} }
{\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{definitionn}
Une ........................ associe à chaque nombre réel $x$ d'un     
................................ un nombre réel que l'on note ...........  et     
qu'on appelle  ................................ de $x$.
\end{definitionn}

\begin{tcolorbox}[width=17cm]
\textbf{\underline{Définition}} Une ........................ associe à     
chaque nombre réel $x$ d'un ................................ un nombre réel 
que l'on note ...........  et qu'on appelle  
................................ de $x$.
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I added a working code at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stretching is due to `\setstretch{1.4}` and the space after `\textbf{\underline{Définition}}`. Yes, that space matters!

Fixed code (by removing the space and use `\normalfont` in `definitionn`):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry} %avoid overfull warnings
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.4}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{definitionn}
{\begin{tcolorbox}[width=17cm]
\normalfont\textbf{\underline{Définition}}}%note the removed space here
{\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{definitionn}
Une ........................ associe à chaque nombre réel $x$ d'un     
................................ un nombre réel que l'on note ...........  et     
qu'on appelle  ................................ de $x$.
\end{definitionn}

\begin{tcolorbox}[width=17cm]
\textbf{\underline{Définition}} Une ........................ associe à     
chaque nombre réel $x$ d'un ................................ un nombre réel 
que l'on note ...........  et qu'on appelle  
................................ de $x$.
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So the problem was that space (the \setstretch stretches both cases consistently), I tried adding it to the regular code to check and I indeed got the same result. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I get identical output with a simple fix:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.4}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{definitionn}
 {\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth]\textbf{\underline{Définition}} \ignorespaces}
 {\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{definitionn}
Une ........................ associe à chaque nombre réel $x$ d'un
................................ un nombre réel que l'on note ...........  et
qu'on appelle  ................................ de $x$.
\end{definitionn}

\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth]
\textbf{\underline{Définition}} Une ........................ associe à
chaque nombre réel $x$ d'un ................................ un nombre réel
que l'on note ...........  et qu'on appelle
................................ de $x$.
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

I also changed the arbitrary `17cm` to `\textwidth`.

What's the problem? According to your definition, there are *two* spaces after the word “Définition”, one from the replacement text, the other one from the line end after `\begin{definitionn}`. By adding `\ignorespaces` the latter is ignored.

[image]

Comment: The problem was the added space at the end of the \begin brackets when defining the environment. When setting the witdth to \textwidth the spacing changes so the problem doesn't happen and you get the same results.